# Where are notes stored on Xiaomi devices?

Tags: internal-storage, xiaomi, notes

The screen of my phone is dead, and I would like to find the notes I have on my phone.

I use a SD card. I found a folder on the SD card named `com.miui.notes` with a folder named `files` inside of it.

But this folder is empty although I had a few notes created on my phone.

How do I find them?

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/fhc7tw/where_are_my_notes_saved_locally/) the data is also not stored in `Internal Storage/Android/Data/com.miui.notes`. That leaves only the app-private storage under `/data/data/com.miui.notes/` where you only have access to on rooted devices. If you have adb access you can try `adb backup com.miui.notes`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I do that?

Comment: If you don't know how you have most likely adb not enabled on the phone and the PC authorized, then this option isn't accessible unless you can navigate on the phone blindly. Then the only way to access the data would be the Google Cloud backup if the apps stores the notes there and you have a Google-Account set-up on the phone + backup enabled.

Comment: you could try MHL HDMI multiport adapter and connect TV + mouse

Comment: Since the notes are stored on my SD card, if I put the card in another xiaomi phone, will I access the notes on the new phone?

Comment: I would be surprised if the notes app makes use of the sd-card. And if you have formatted the sd-card as internal storage everything is encrypted and bound to the phone hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Notes are stored in SQLite database `/data/user/0/com.miui.notes/databases/note.db` and therefore the file is not accessible to user without root.
You can find your notes in Mi Cloud if MIUI account is allowed to sync.